# Can I use NetTcpBinding with transport security (https) but without client certificate

Tags: wcf, ssl, nettcpbinding, transport

We run NetTcpBinding with SecurityMode.None.

Now we also want encryption of the sent data. Set SecurityMode to *Transport* seems not enough, because the client cant connect to the server anymore (that worked before this change) although the server is started.

What else do I need to change?

Comment: Is SSL/HTTPS enabled in IIS for your site?

Comment: The guy who knows that has holidays... What if YES/NO ? what would be the options?

Comment: If it's not enabled, and you're saying you want to use SSL for transport security, then your service won't work.

Comment: Do you have me a link maybe msdn where its written that netctp + transport + IIS (enabled ssl) need to work together?

Comment: Does it work for IIS 6.0 AND 7.0 ? can both IIS enable the ssl for wcf ?

Comment: I forgot to mention we do not host the wcf service in IIS. We host it in a windows Service.

Answer (score 6):

HTTPS is part of the HTTP protocol.

NetTcpBinding uses a binary protcol which is not HTTP. Therefore you cannot use HTTPS with NetTcp.

For securing NetTcp see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789011.aspx